# Finding change of basis with only the knowledge of a set of homomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, change-of-basis

I came across two different sets of matrices of the same group representation. Naturally, I wanted to see how they relate, i.e. find the explicit change of basis. All the matrices have the same eigenvalues and are diagonalisable, but they have different eigenvectors. A priori, I do not have any knowledge about the bases involved.

Let me denote the two sets of matrices by $V_i$ and $W_i$. Now if all the $V_i$ would have the same eigenspaces, and all the $W_i$ would have the same eigenspaces, I could decompose as follows:

$$PV_iP^{-1}=D=QW_iQ^{-1},$$

with $D$ being diagonal. Hence I would have found a transition matrix $T=Q^{-1}P$ such that

$$TV_iT^{-1} = W_i.$$

I am wondering if I can do something similar in the case where the $V_i$ do not have the same eigenspaces. My aim is to find a change of basis without the explicit knowledge of the bases involved.

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments, I add here concretely which representation I am talking about. It is the reduced Burau representation of the braid groups, acting on a $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$-module, given by the matrices

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V_i = &
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{1}_{i-2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & q & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -q & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathbb{1}_{n-i-1}
\end{bmatrix}, \text{ for } 1 < i < n; \\
V_1 = & 
\begin{bmatrix}
-q & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mathbb{1}_{n-2}
\end{bmatrix};
V_n =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{1}_{n-2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & q \\
0 & 0 & -q
\end{bmatrix}
.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
With respect to another basis, they look as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
W_i = & 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{1}_{i-2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -q & -q & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathbb{1}_{n-i-1}
\end{bmatrix}, \text{ for } 1 < i < n; \\
W_1 = &
\begin{bmatrix}
-q & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mathbb{1}_{n-2}
\end{bmatrix};
W_n = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{1}_{n-2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -q & -q \\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
(considered as block matrices, where $\mathbb{1}_k$ denotes the $k \times k$ identity matrix).

Comment: More details about your two representations?

Comment: I added the concrete representation in my question. But the crucial point here is that it is just one representation, with respect to two different bases.